# Change package mode of JCR Package

Tags: aem, jcr

Is there a way to change the packaging mode of an existing JCR package from replace to update? As far as I know the packaging mode cannot be set in the AEM Package Manager dialogs.
What exactly would I have to do? Just change the filter.xml and repackage? Somehow, this didn't work for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to change the `filter.xml` as well as the `.content.xml` in the `definition` subfolder.

Here is a small batchscript that unpacks, changes the mode and repacks a package.

If you save it as *modPkg*, you cann call it with two params:

```
modPkg FILENAME FITLERMODE
```

where `FILENAME` is the filename of the package and `FILTERMODE` should be `merge`, `update` or `replace`.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=${1}
filterMode=${2}
echo "Extracting package."
jar xf $1
echo "Modifying filter.xml."
perl -pe 's|(root="[^\"]+")(( )*mode="[^\"]+"( )*)?(( )*(/)?>)|\1 mode="'"${filterMode}"'"\5|g' META-INF/vault/filter.xml > META-INF/vault/filter.xml.backup
rm -rf META-INF/vault/filter.xml
mv META-INF/vault/filter.xml.backup META-INF/vault/filter.xml
echo "Modifying .content.xml in definition-folder."
perl -pe 's|mode="[^\"]+"|mode="'"${filterMode}"'"|g' META-INF/vault/definition/.content.xml > META-INF/vault/definition/.content.xml.backup
rm -rf META-INF/vault/definition/.content.xml
mv META-INF/vault/definition/.content.xml.backup META-INF/vault/definition/.content.xml
echo "Repackaging."
jar -cfM ${filterMode}-${filename} META-INF jcr_root
echo "Deleting temp files."
rm -rf META-INF
rm -rf jcr_root
echo "Finished."
```

There might be more elegant ways to do the job, but it's easy enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the script, quite useful :)